# What will be the output of the code below?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on some typical Javascript interview questions and came across this one. I'm confused about the answer and the explanation and am wondering if someone could go more in depth and rephrase it.

What will be the output of the code below?

```js
var y = 1;
if (function f() {}) {
  y += typeof f;
}
console.log(y);
```

Explanation:
The output would be 1undefined. The if condition statement evaluates using eval, so eval(function f(){}) returns function f(){} (which is true). Therefore, inside the if statement, executing typeof f returns undefined because the if statement code executes at run time, and the statement inside the if condition is evaluated during run time.

Comment: no, the if condition is *truthy* because a *function* is truthy

Comment: You [should not be asking us](/help/on-topic): you have a JS engine built into your browser, what you should be doing as part of your own [searching and researching](/help/how-to-ask) is opening dev tools, pasting that code, and simply running it. If your question is _not_ "what is the output", but it's actually "why is the output..." then update your post, and title.

Comment: I love these questions but wonder if they're used in real business code? Not to judge I'm wondering just because I'm still in school...

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh I'd hope not. ESLint will forbid this code due to violating [no-constant-condition](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-constant-condition). It'll also be able to statically analyze the code and detect that a `f` variable name does not exist, so any attempt to use `f` (other than with `typeof`) will throw a linting error as well.

Answer (score 3):

> The if condition statement evaluates using eval

No, not at all. What's inside the `if` condition is a **function expression**, and functions (like all Javascript objects) are truthy.

Function expressions by themselves (unlike function declarations - that is, `function fnName() { ...` on their own line) don't result in the function receiving a variable name in the current scope, so `f` is not seen as a variable name - it's just the name of the function for the function expression.

The function expression gets evaluated as truthy inside the `if` condition, and then is not referenced again. There is no variable named `f` in scope anywhere in the code, so `typeof f` resolves to `undefined` (`typeof f` will resolve to `undefined` no matter where it's placed in the code there).

In contrast, if `f` was a **function declaration** on its own line, a variable name named `f` *would* be created (and therefore `typeof f` would result in `function`):

```js
var y = 1;
function f() {}
if (true) {
  y += typeof f;
}
console.log(y);
```